# On some basic properties of cumulative distribution functions

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

This is a question on some remark of Terry Tao's note on introductory probability theory:

https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/09/29/275a-notes-0-foundations-of-probability-theory/comment-page-2/#comment-680144

Regarding the remarks after Corollary 27, I see that by using the probability space model $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B[\mathbb R], \mu)$, where $\mathcal B[\mathbb R]$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb R$, $\mu$ the Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure associated to ${F}$, any function ${F: {\mathbb R} \rightarrow [0,1]}$ obeying the properties (i)-(iii) of Exercise 26 can be seen as the CDF of the real random variable $X$ modeled by the identity map on $R$.

But why does it follow that given a real random variable $X$, modeled on some general sample space $\Omega$, its CDF also obeys the given properties as well? (After all, Exercise 26 can only cover the case for CDF of real random variables modeled on $\mathbb R$.)

Comment: The claim is for real random variables but starting from different measurable spaces or sigma-algebras. You will need to use the pullback property in Example 12.

Comment: @Henry: To clarify: Given a real random variable $X$, modeled on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mu)$, we can define the function $\mu': \mathcal B[\mathbb R] \rightarrow [0, 1]$ by setting $\mu'(S) := \mu(X^{-1}(S))$. By Example 12, $\mu'$ is a probability measure on $R$ (with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra), as it's essentially $\mu$ restricted to the pullback $X^*(\mathcal B[\mathbb R])$. Then $X$ agrees in distribution to the real random variable in Exercise 26, modeled on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B[\mathbb R], \mu')$, thus its' CDF must obey the  same properties.

Comment: @Henry: So Example 12 is needed to make sure that the function $\mu'$ is indeed a probability measure. Is it correct?